# comparing two lists and finding indices of changes

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to compare two lists and find the position and changed character at that position. For example, these are two lists:

```
list1 = ['I', 'C', 'A', 'N', 'R', 'U', 'N']
list2 = ['I', 'K', 'A', 'N', 'R', 'U', 'T']
```

I want to be able to output the position and change for the differences in the two lists. As you can see, a letter can be repeated multiple times at a different index position. This is the code that I have tried, but I can't seem to print out the second location accurately.

```
for indexing in range(0, len(list1)):
    if list1[indexing] != list2[indexing]:
        dontuseindex = indexing
        poschange = indexing + 1
        changecharacter = list2[indexing]
for indexingagain in range(dontuseindex + 1, len(list1)):
    if list1[indexingagain] != list2[indexingagain]:
        secondposchange = indexingagain + 1
        secondchangecharacter = list2[indexingagain]
```

Is there a better way to solve this problem or any suggestions to the code I have?

My expected output would be:

```
2    K
7    T
```

Comment: Are you just concerned with replacements, or also insertions/deletions? In the first case: Just `zip`and compare; in the latter case, use a variant of [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: @PeterWood have listed my expected output

Comment: @tobias_k I'm only concerned with replacements. The lists will always be the same length

Comment: Obviously `[print(ix, *thing) for ix, thing in enumerate(map(set, zip(list1, list2))) if len(thing) == 2]` is the only good way to do it

Comment: Just to note, the indices are `1` and `6`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
for index, (first, second) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)):
    if first != second:
        print(index, second)
```

Output:

```
1 K
6 T
```

If you want the output you gave, we need to count from `1` instead of the usual `0`:

```
for index, (first, second) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2), start=1):
```

Comment: I think this should work well and I should be able to implement it easily. Thank you!

Comment: Is there an easy way to store both the changes and indices into two separate variables? For example, `position1`, `position2`, `change1`, `change2`?

Comment: What if there are 3 changes? Maybe you should think about this a bit and ask it as a separate question, after searching.

Comment: Note that OP's indices start with 1, so maybe `enumerate(zip(list1, list2), start=1)`?

Comment: @tobias_k I must admit, I'm not sure what the original example is doing

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility to save all the not-equal elements with the index is with a list comprehensions:

```
list1 = ['I', 'C', 'A', 'N', 'R', 'U', 'N']
list2 = ['I', 'K', 'A', 'N', 'R', 'U', 'T']

# Append index, element1 and element2 as tuple to the list if they are not equal
changes = [(i, list1[i], list2[i]) for i in range(len(list1)) if list1[i] != list2[i]]
print(changes)
#prints [(1, 'C', 'K'), (6, 'N', 'T')]
```

Not exactly what you specified as output but it's close.

You could print the specified output with a loop:

```
for i in changes:
    print(i[0] + 1, i[1])
# 2 K
# 7 T
```

In the comments several alternative ways of designing the list comprehension were suggested:

- Using `enumerate` and `zip`:

  ```
  changes = [(i, e1, e2) for i, (e1, e2) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)) if e1 != e2]
  ```
- Using `enumerate` with start index and `zip`:

  ```
  changes = [(i, e1, e2) for i, (e1, e2) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2), 1)  if e1 != e2]
  ```
- Using `zip` and [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

  ```
  import itertools
  changes = [(i, e1, e2) for i, e1, e2 in zip(itertools.count(), list1, list2)) if e1 != e2]
  ```
- Using `zip` and [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) with start-index:

  ```
  changes = [(i, e1, e2) for i, e1, e2 in zip(itertools.count(1), list1, list2)) if e1 != e2]
  ```

All of them producing the same result as the original but using different (better) python features.

Comment: Why not `zip` and `enumerate`?

Comment: It's not very pythonic.

Comment: @PeterWood - Okay, with that much peer pressure - I've included it at the end.

Comment: I don't think it's peer pressure to question the style of code being presented. If you compare the two solutions you've posted, the second is cleaner, has less room for error, and is easier to comprehend. You use `list1` and `list2` only once each as opposed to 3 and 2 previously. You use `i` only once as opposed to 5 times previously. Also, there will be no error if `list2` is shorter than `list1`.

Comment: @PeterWood You raise an interesting question: If both lists have different lengths would that count as a difference? I know that the `zip` and `enumerate` are the better choices in this case, it was just presenting an alternative given that you provided that pythonic kind of iteration already. I think I'll leave it as the alternative in the answer. I didn't felt any peer-pressure that was just a remark about the two upvotes on your first comment. :-)

Comment: OP says the lists will be the same length, so it's not part of the requirements.

Comment: I was thinking, `zip(count(), list1, list2)` would be more uniform as there wouldn't be the strange tuple unpacking syntax. Uses [**`itertools.count`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count)

Comment: Good catch! I did spent almost 15 minutes searching for that function when writing the answer! Especially since that has a start argument that would fulfill the OPs indexing requirement.

Comment: [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) allows for setting the `start` index, as well. No need for `count`. That's exactly what  `enumerate` is there for!

Comment: I've included this as well. Never realized it had this parameter. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ['I', 'C', 'A', 'N', 'R', 'U', 'N']
list2 = ['I', 'K', 'A', 'N', 'R', 'U', 'T']
[i for i, x in enumerate(zip(list1,list2)) if x[0]!=x[1]]
```

Output:

```
[1, 6]
```